# How can I find the x coordinate of the contentView that is equal to the center x of a UIScrollView's frame

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I have a `UIScrollView` that scrolls horizontally.  I have about 10 views lined up horizontally in that scrollview.  I want to find the view that contains the center point of the scrollview's frame (not contentView.frame) as it scrolls.  I am thinking to use the `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` `UIScrollView` delegate method, but I am not sure how to find this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the start-point of a frame of a view (`myChildView`) in the reference of another view (`scrollView`) using the following code:

```
CGPoint origin = [myChildView convertPoint:CGPointMake(myChildView.bounds.origin.x, myChildView.bounds.origin.y) toView:[self scrollView]];
```

Use the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method to pick your views and perform the calculations there.